# EXC_BAD_ACCESS only on device, only with arm64 architecture defined

Tags: ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, arm64

I am facing a "EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2" issue, but only on my device, and only when arm64 architecture is used.
If I understand well, code=2 means an access to an unauthorized area.

The code itself:

```
NSLog(@"%@ %@",pngPath,viewImage.debugDescription);
[UIImagePNGRepresentation(viewImage) writeToFile:pngPath atomically:YES];
```

If I comment 2nd line, no issue any more. If I replace variables with whatever else (e.g. [UIImage imageNamed:@"..."], ...) I still get the crash.

This problem only appears when I decided to include arm64 architecture: this code has been used for a while.

Thanks for any suggestion.
FL

Comment: Check the device log for suspicious messages.  Check the debug console in Xcode for any exception messages that go along with the crash.  Post the stack trace from the crash (type 'bt' in the debug console).

Comment: Thanks for proposal. I applied recommendation, but no obvious conclusion.

If I skip various "[self.view addSubview:...]" no issue. But as soon as I do it again, even if delayed few seconds after initial launch of the App, crashes occurs on 1st line of drawRect... Whatever the code on this 1st line

Comment: Just before adding the UIViews, I printed a decription:
        NSLog(@"%@",self.view.description);
        NSLog(@"%@",theHorHistoricalView.description);
----
<UIView: 0x17418f150; frame = (0 20; 320 568); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x174035720>>
----
<HistoricalView: 0x13fe36790; frame = (0 -320; 412.5 320); layer = <CALayer: 0x174226ec0>>

Comment: Maybe a lead: in one of the 2 Apps which was concerned by EXC_BAD_ACCESS - only with arm64 enabled and only on device - I used this function: isnan(A) . Replacing it by (A!=A) just made it work ! The other App is still problematic though

Answer (score 0):

Finally... I had at least 1 major issue maybe 2:
1/ first I used a great deal of CGFloat, which for some reasons was obviously not appropriate: switching from 4 bytes to 8 bytes is not transparent in my applications.
2/ I used function isnan().
For second item not sure this was critical. But during my trials the removing of isnan() had one App working again. Thus not transparent neither